# PowerBi - DAX - assign a value in a new column if string contains

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

what i am trying to do is to get a value in a calculated column from a string.
column 1 has apple;orange;pear;banana
now, if column 1 contains all those values then the value in the calculated column should be 8
if column 1 only contains 2 of those values then the value should be 4
if column 1 only contains 3 values then it should be 6 and if column 1 only contains 1 value then the value of the column should be 2.

easy right? that's what i though, but as i am unable to figure out.I tried with if(or(containsstring but it s going to assign the value 8 for all of them. i tried also with strict if ="string" but if there will be a row with apple it s not going to assign a value.

hope i was clear enough.

| column1 | calculated column |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple;orange;pear;banana | 8 | points / specific value - 2 |
| apple | 2 | apple;orange;pear;banana - correct values |
| apple;orange | 4 | strawberry - wrong value - 0 |
| orange;banana | 4 |  |
| pear;banana;apple | 6 |  |
| strawberry | 0 |  |
|  |  |  |
| strawberry | 0 |  |
|  |  |  |

Comment: I think you need to post a small representative dataset together with expected results.

Comment: @JosWoolley , of course, do you mean like plain text?

Comment: Well, a few examples in a 2-column table would be useful, input plus expected output.

Comment: @JosWoolley done!

Comment: Where are the "searched-for" values going to come from?  Is it a hard-coded list?  Is there another table that contains which values are worth points?

Comment: @JodyHighroller - thanks for the answer! it s a hard coded list (manually) and i also assign the values manually ( i m pretty flexible on this one so i can create a dimensional table in sql with the values and the point equivalent) if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following for the calculated column

```
Column = 
VAR _1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( 'Table', "new", SUBSTITUTE ( 'Table'[col1], ";", "|" ) )
VAR _2 =
    GENERATE (
        _1,
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [new] ) ),
            "_txt", TRIM ( PATHITEM ( [new], [Value], TEXT ) )
        )
    )
VAR _3 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        _2,
        "score1", MAXX ( FILTER ( Lookup, EARLIER ( [_txt] ) = Lookup[Column1] ), Lookup[score] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAXX (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                'Table',
                "score", SUMX ( FILTER ( _3, EARLIER ( 'Table'[col1] ) = [col1] ), [score1] )
            ),
            [score]
        )
    )
```

which will give you this

[image: S1]

If you have a Lookup table like this

[image: S2]

Comment: i think i am getting somewhere but  i have the following error : --function add columns cannot ad column [score] since it already exists--. What i did i replicated the lookup table but it s saying :Function 'ADDCOLUMNS' cannot add column [score] since it already exists - i tried deleting it,then it wont actually see it.  --- main is the table where the values are added and lookup is the lookup table :

Comment: Do you already have a column called score in Table. The calculated column should be done in Table not in Lookup

Comment: yes , absolutely, i am writing the new calculated column called Column in the main table,not in the lookup one

Comment: i just restarted my power bi, and it works now. awesome! thank you very much!

Comment: one last question though, will this compare the whole string when it does the "scoring" or just parts of it if they match? -- as if i have in the lookup table a value applebees;apple i think it counts it twice,as the score is 10 instead of 8.

Comment: The code internally splits the string based on `;` delimiter and compare each string in lookup, gets score, sums up and gives you rolledup value on the original table. If you are in trouble create a thread in power bi community and tag me with @. What is the full string?

Comment: i tried posting this in power bi community on powerbi forum but unfortunately i am unable to register/sign in .-- Computers with Windows operating system ;Computers with MAC operating system;Phones with Android operating system;Phones with iOS operating system;Tablets; -- full choice of options

,i've split them up in the lookup table with the value 2 for each, and i get for the full string (above) 20 instead of 10.

Comment: What are you searching for in `Computers with Windows operating system ;Computers with MAC operating system;Phones with Android operating system;Phones with iOS operating system;Tablets` meaning how your lookup table looks like

Comment: ugh i don t have enough rep to chat, i m looking for the whole string subset of Computers with Windows operating system ;Computers with MAC operating system;Phones with Android operating system;Phones with iOS operating system;Tablets --- so the user can choose between those options but also all of them. So i am looking for matchcase each option, thats why i was asking if the lookup table filters based on the whole string from that sort of array of options

Comment: Having difficulties understanding the req. Can you create another thread in stack and once done write a comment here with the link to the new Q. I will take a look but please post the data representative of your issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205990/dax-powerbi-match-subset-string-strictly-from-array-and-assign-value-to-it -- here you go. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This lets you assign points to each item from another query (named points), and calculate the points total for each row from this query's Column1

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Column1"},points,{"Column1"},"zzz",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table6" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "zzz", {"Column2"}, {"Column2"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Table6", {"Index"}, {
    {"Column1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Column1], Text.From), ";"), type text},
    {"Points", each List.Sum([Column2]), type number}
}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, is there a way to assign a value for the specific string? in case the user will select strawberries ,it s going to assign 2 points to it. -- later edit,the page just reloaded , how would this translate in dax?

Comment: I've put in a sample of assigning points to each value. From here, if that doesnt work, then explain the request better

Comment: thank you! is there a way to translate that in DAX?

Comment: DAX solution is possible

Comment: @smpa01 sounds good!