# DAX - PowerBi - Match subset string strictly from array and assign value to it

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

```
Column = 
    VAR _1 =
        ADDCOLUMNS ( 'digital_competences_q3', "new", SUBSTITUTE ( digital_competences_q3[q3_a], ";", "|" ) )
    VAR _2 =
        GENERATE (
            _1,
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [new] ) ),
                "_txt", TRIM ( PATHITEM ( [new], [Value], TEXT ) )
            )
        )
    VAR _3 =
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            _2,
            "score", MAXX ( FILTER ( 'lookup', EARLIER ( [_txt] ) = 'lookup'[Column1] ), 'lookup'[score] )
        )
    RETURN
        CALCULATE (
            MAXX (
                ADDCOLUMNS (
                    'digital_competences_q3',
                    "score", SUMX ( FILTER ( _3, EARLIER ( digital_competences_q3[q3_a] ) = [q3_a] ), [score] )
                ),
                [score]
            )
        )
```

moving from this code which was so graciously provided by @smpa01 the user can select any of the options from this array : `Computers with Windows operating system ;Computers with MAC operating system;Phones with Android operating system;Phones with iOS operating system;Tablets;`

stand alone choices are :

- Computers with Windows operating system
- Computers with MAC operating system
- Phones with Android operating system
- Phones with iOS operating system
- Tablets

after the user selects their choice (which can be multiple) the array created will contain the options separated by ";"

the main table has the column with the array selected
the lookup table has the options with the value (2) assigned to each one.

if all options are selected the sum is 20 instead of 10.

so the question is, is it matching the entire value from the lookup table column1? or based on common words? as we can see the single IOS value gets scored correctly.

Comment: so you want to provide users a slicer(from lookup table) and and a measure to generate the count as per the slicer strings (from lookup table) contained in the fact string? please confirm

Comment: the data that is being fed into the database that the bi is connected to looks like that array,what i am trying to do is assign the value from the lookup table to the values in the main table, like we discussed previously and the concept worked on the apple/pear etc scenario, i can t really understand why it doesn't work on strings and doubles up the value. it doesnt split them by space,but by ; so i have no idea what it s matching. You can try on your end on the exact same structure but change the values to match mine.

Comment: The string that you provided it should result 10

Comment: yes,i know, but if you have a look at the images provided,it s 20 :|

Comment: do you have the same string twice in the dataset?

Comment: on the same row,i do not, only unique values are selected. that was also my 1st thought , and refreshed the db,and bi .

Comment: Can you upload your power bi file in google drive and share the link here? I can't reproduce the issue at my end. It gives me 10.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot as it contains confidential user data, were you able to replicate using the same values? what i can do is provide screenshots with the array in the rows, i will edit my post now.

Comment: edited my post with the 2 new screenshots.

Comment: give me the entire row of `digital_competences_q3[q3_a]`. Don't post picture, edit your question and provide the values in table format after you convert the `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support`

Comment: so you do have `Computers with Windows operating system ;Computers with MAC operating system;Phones with Android operating system;Phones with iOS operating system;Tablets;` twice in the dataset; row1 and row 3?

Comment: yes, on different rows yes, but on the same row i do not. is that the issue ?:|

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. Cause DAX is summing up the total value by each unique q3_a internally. Try this new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Column =
VAR _1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        'digital_competences_q3',
        "new", SUBSTITUTE ( digital_competences_q3[q3_a], ";", "|" )
    )
VAR _2 =
    GENERATE (
        _1,
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [new] ) ),
            "_txt", TRIM ( PATHITEM ( [new], [Value], TEXT ) )
        )
    )
VAR _3 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        _2,
        "score",
            MAXX (
                FILTER ( '_lookup', EARLIER ( [_txt] ) = '_lookup'[Column1] ),
                '_lookup'[score]
            )
    )
VAR _4 =
    CALCULATE ( COUNTX ( digital_competences_q3, digital_competences_q3[q3_a] ) )
VAR _5 =
    CALCULATE (
        MAXX (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                'digital_competences_q3',
                "score",
                    SUMX (
                        FILTER ( _3, EARLIER ( digital_competences_q3[q3_a] ) = [q3_a] ),
                        [score]
                    )
            ),
            [score]
        )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( _5, _4 )
```

[image: S1]

**EDIT**

```
Column = 
    VAR _1 =
        ADDCOLUMNS ( 'digital_competences_q3', "new", SUBSTITUTE ( digital_competences_q3[q3_a], ";", "|" ) )
    VAR _2 =
        GENERATE (
            _1,
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [new] ) ),
                "_txt", TRIM ( PATHITEM ( [new], [Value], TEXT ) )
            )
        )
    VAR _3 =
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            _2,
            "score", MAXX ( FILTER ( '_lookup', EARLIER ( [_txt] ) = '_lookup'[Column1] ), '_lookup'[score] )
        )
    VAR _4 = CALCULATE(COUNT(digital_competences_q3[q3_a]),ALLEXCEPT(digital_competences_q3,digital_competences_q3[q3_a]))
    VAR _5 = 
        CALCULATE (
            MAXX (
                ADDCOLUMNS (
                    'digital_competences_q3',
                    "score", SUMX ( FILTER ( _3, EARLIER ( digital_competences_q3[q3_a] ) = [q3_a] ), [score] )
                ),
                [score]
            )
        )
RETURN DIVIDE(_5,_4)
```

Comment: i hope you are not going to hate me, because i owe you a beer, but it s the exact same result.

Comment: Does changing VAR _4 to ` VAR _4 = CALCULATE(COUNTX(digital_competences_q3,digital_competences_q3[q3_a]),ALLEXCEPT(digital_competences_q3,digital_competences_q3[q3_a]))` help?

Comment: um,yes it did, it got fixed by that.I don t know who you are, and how are you this skilled but i am very thankful for it and let me know where i can send you a beer.

Comment: no worries mate !!! I know how hard DAX is. I had sleepless nights initially and after a lot of practice(I MEAN A LOT),  I feel I have some grip on it now..nothing more that. Participate here only to be better myself.

Comment: i am jealous now, and i really wanna get to learn more DAX but the thing is i can t randomly practice,i need a project/assignment. for me to be motivated to research it .Any tips on learning?

Comment: try to answer questions that people have here on stack, it gives you real use cases and opportunity to practice.